# AngularJS Directives and the Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I'm not sure this question's been asked, but is it *good practice* (not ok-to-do) to mess with the data model from an AngularJS directive?

For instance, if in my controller I have some object, like:

```
 app.controller("MyCtrl", function () {
      $scope.obj.setOfKnives = ["Ginsu", "Steak"];
 });
```

And I had some button with a directive on it like (written for brevity):

```
 <button add-knife>Add a Knife</button/>
```

In that add-knife directive, is it good practice (again, not ok-to-do) to mess with that setOfKnives array, something like:

```
 app.directive("addKnife", function () {

      return {
          "restrict": "A",
          "link": function (scope, element, attr) {
                scope.addAKnife = function (theKnife) {
                    scope.obj.setOfKnives.push(theKnife);
                };

                element.on("click", function () {
                    scope.addAKnife("Serrated");
                });
          }
      };
 });
```

*(I believe it'd be better to make that directive an element directive w/ a template...)*
So is this good practice? Or should I use the directive to add DOM objects to the page and have some controller function take care of adding and removing items from the setOfKnives array based on the DOM?

Comment: I would add/remove items in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manipulating the model inside the directive is the way to go. Direct DOM manipulation should be avoided.

To make the directive more modular, you can pass the array as an attribute on the directive and create an isolated scope, which limits what get shared between the controller that directive.

```
<button add-knife knives="setOfKnives" >Add a Knife</button/>
```

In directive

```
app.directive("addKnife", function () {

      return {
          "restrict": "A",
           scope:{ knives:'='},
           "link": function (scope, element, attr) {
                 scope.addAKnife = function (theKnife) {
                    scope.knives.push(theKnife);
                };

          }
      };
 });
```

Directives make more sense when you treat them as reusable UI elements. For one off cases you can always do manipulation on controller scope and the databinding feature of angular should do the rest.

Comment: but let's say I have some ng-repeat that displays out the knives as they are added...if i did <span ng-repeat="knife in knives" ...> would it bind as I did the scope.knives.push?

Comment: Yes, as long the directive and controller share the same references to knives, this would update and refresh on UI DOM too. I think if you are creating directive just to add a knive and update DOM based on the addition, you dont require directive at all.

Comment: First off, thanks @Chandermani for the help. The problem is that I'm dealing with multiple scopes and I'm trying to affect the data model of all of them through the directive.

Answer (score 0):

anyway ,
 you will have the access of internal state of DOM and you can change the model inside the directive but directives are custom controls which are designed to use across various pages so ideally it should behave like other controls and the custom logic must be delegated to Services / controllers so that directive can be reused without change